# How to send axios PUT request with array

Tags: axios

I am trying to send an axios PUT request with some parameters in the URL, and some data in the body. My code is as follows:

```
axios(
{ method: 'put',
  url:  'https://api2.************.com/edgewebapi/Dev2/booths/combine?databaseName=07demo&boundary=0',
  data: { boothNumbers: [1916,1918] },
headers : {'Authorization': 'Basic VUdFUTdDZkY6RmJsb0QyWiQ=' }
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
```

I get an error "'400 Value cannot be null. Parameter name: boothNumbers", Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong in creating the axios request? I have googled for hours ant ried every suggestion that relates to this, without luck. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do a PUT request using axios as follows:

axios.put(url[, data[, config]])

For more details , please refer to the below link.

https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config